# Performance of Dedicated vs Virtual Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, performance

I have an application that's running in both dedicated and virtual server environments (all Windows Server 2008 R2). Given nearly identical specifications of the servers (memory, processors), the application running on the virtual server drastically underperforms the one running on the dedicated server in terms of time to execute a complex task, taking 2 times as long to execute. During this task, the processor utilization of the virtual server continually runs at about 30% although it rarely goes above that level. The dedicated server processor utilization never goes above 5%. There's plenty of free memory on both servers and I don't see any disk read/write bottlenecks.

I want to be able to recommend that the virtual server needs more resources to improve performance but I'm not sure what those resources should be as it doesn't appear that anything is overtaxed based on the performance indicators.

Is there something I'm missing in terms of why my application runs so much slower on the virtual server given the same application?

Answer (score 1):

One difference may be that in most hypervisors not all performance enhancing CPU features  are made available to guests.  (That is among other reasons because for instance live migration won't be successful when a guest is using CPU extensions on the old host that are not present on the target host.)

By default most hypervisors will only expose a limited but almost universally compatible subset of CPU features. If your application benefits from such, they may at the time of testing have only been available in your bare-metal server.

A good example of CPU features that could be missing in both [KVM (Qemu)](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_KVM) and [Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn859550(v%3Dws.11)) guests with default settings are the [AES and AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) instruction set that will significantly normally speed up AES encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 1):

This is, unfortunately, expected. [Virtualization has a significant impact on performance](https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2020/10/13/virtualization-performance-overheads-part-2/) of CPU intensive applications, especially if there is a high level of process concurrency. I have been testing the [performance impact of virtualization](https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2020/03/19/virtual-performance-or-lack-thereof/) over the years, and while things have improved over the past decade, they haven't improved all that much. Even the current generation of AMD CPUs which are unburdened by spectre and metdown mitigations exhibit a [performance penalty of 17-25% when virtualized](https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2020/10/21/virtualization-performance-penalty-mitigations/) on an purely CPU bound workload.

The high overhead manifests particularly badly under a heavy load with high concurrency, because context switching is made much more expensive under a hypervisor. A light workload with low concurrency suffers a relatively minimal performance penalty, but a heavily concurrent workload that saturates the guest CPU performs significantly worse.

Some of the performance overhead can be mitigated by:

1. Pinning vCPUs to physical CPUs
2. Allocating the guest memory from huge memory pages (2MB vs. 4KB).

On latest AMD CPUs, this will typically limit the overhead to no more than 20% even under a heavy concurrent workload.

Answer (score 0):

Only looking at system wide utilization of CPU/memory/disk will not solve many performance problems.

Profile the application to see what exactly is slow. On Windows, try [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/) (fka Xperf). Data can be compared and visualized in many ways, including [flame graphs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/graphs#flame_graphs).

---

Virtualized complicates things because it is possible to do silly things like oversubscribe or throttle a host's resources without it being obvious from the guest. Compare "dedicated server" versus virtualized with only one VM on the host using with all the host's resources. That is a more fair comparison to find any overhead of virtualization vs bare metal.